# Filter prime numbers from stream of BigIntegers

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, biginteger

How to filter prime numbers from a stream of BigIntegers in java without using isProbablePrime() function ?

I tried this code but cannot solve the error:

```
List<BigInteger> x =bigIntList.stream().filter(n->n >1 && IntStream.range(2,n).noneMatch(index->n%index==0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Brute force,  loop from 2 to sqrt(num) and divide along the way..

Comment: @Pritam I tried using isProbablePrime()  but cannot figure out the idea without using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help :

```
public static boolean isBigPrime(BigInteger n) {
    if (n.compareTo(new BigInteger("2")) < 0) return false;
    else if (n.compareTo(new BigInteger("2")) == 0) return true;
    for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("2"); i.compareTo(n.divide(new BigInteger("2"))) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
        if (n.mod(i).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

For more refer [here](http://code.mikeyaworski.com/java/prime_factorization_old).

This is how you use Stream.

```
List<BigInteger> prime = l.stream().filter(b -> b.isProbablePrime(1) == true ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It is useful but i was asking for the code to get prime numbers list from stream of BigIntegers.

Comment: @asteriskbimal I changed the code to find prime numbers from stream(). Hope that helps.